# Generate XML elements based on attribute in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am in need to generate XML elements based on attribute values. I use `<xsl:call-template>`. But ends with infinite loops. I need to generate `<colspec>` elements with the values based on `<tgroup>` elements based on the following conditions:
1. Generate `<colspec>` elements based on the string-length of the  elements
2. Also generate attributes for `<colspec>` element like colname='col1' colnum='1' and finally align="left" if the cols attribute has 'l' or align='right' if the cols attribute has 'r' based on the occurence of the values

Sample XML:

```
<table>
    <tgroup cols="lr">
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>H1</entry>
                <entry>H1</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>B1</entry>
                <entry>B2</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

Output XML:

```
<table>
    <tgroup cols="2">
        <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" align="left"/>
        <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" align="right"/>
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>H1</entry>
                <entry>H1</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>B1</entry>
                <entry>B2</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

I tried below XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tgroup">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="cols">
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length(@cols)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="colsp">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_details" select="@cols"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_count" select="string-length(@cols)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="colsp">
        <xsl:param name="cols_details"/>
        <xsl:param name="cols_count"/>
        <xsl:if test="$cols_count != 0">
            <xsl:variable name="single_col" select="substring($cols_details,1,1)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="cols_details1" select="substring-after($cols_details,$single_col)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="cols_count1" select="string-length($cols_details)"/>
            <colspec colnum="{$cols_count1-$cols_count}" colname="col{$cols_count1}" align="{$align}"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="colsp">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_details1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_count1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this fixed version of your xlst.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tgroup">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="cols">
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length(@cols)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="colsp">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_details" select="@cols"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="colsp">
        <xsl:param name="cols_details"/>
        <xsl:param name="colnr" select="1"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($cols_details) > 0">
            <colspec colnum="{$colnr}" colname="col{$colnr}">
                <xsl:variable name="single_col" select="substring($cols_details,1,1)"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="align">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$single_col='l'">left</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$single_col='r'">right</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$single_col='c'">center</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </colspec>
            <xsl:call-template name="colsp">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols_details" select="substring($cols_details,2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="colnr" select="$colnr+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
    <tgroup cols="3">
        <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" align="left"/>
        <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" align="right"/>
        <colspec colnum="3" colname="col3" align="center"/>
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>H1</entry>
                <entry>H1</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>B1</entry>
                <entry>B2</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```